# SQL Azure Export and Import into local SQL Server 2012 - Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted

Tags: azure, backup, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database which is approximately 10GB in total size.

I wanted to have a local copy of the database for development so I saved an export of the database to my storage account and downloaded it. I was a little suspicious when the backup size was 500MB but I backed up the database twice, the file size was the same both times.

I am using SSMS 2014 on a SQL Server 2012 database and selecting 'import data tier application', the backup appears to be working BUT I get an error with the largest table. The error is:

> **TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
>   Data plan execution failed with message One or more errors occurred.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)
>   One or more errors occurred.
>   One or more errors occurred.
>
> Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted. (System)

I cannot find any examples of others with this problem, but it can't be only me that has it?

FYI When I try to use SSMS 2012 to import that database I get the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Internal Error. The database platform service with type
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is
>   not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must
>   provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
>   (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Which is why I installed 2014.

#

UPDATE, After installing SSMS 2016 I got the same error:

> **TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
>
> ---
>
> Data plan execution failed with message One or more errors occurred.      (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)
>
> ---
>
> One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---
>
> One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---
>
> Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted. (System)
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the latest version of SSMS that you can download and install from [SQL Server Management Studio Download page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

Azure SQL Database has a numerous new features being added in a fast pace manner. SSMS from this unified download page provides up-to-date supports for the latest features in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I download this and got the same error:

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the compressed table data stored in the bacpac file couldn't be decompressed. That can happen if the file gets corrupted at some point during a file copy operation. If it happens with multiple bacpac files, though, that would be concerning. Have you tried exporting the bacpac a second time?

Comment: I have tried this around 5 times, same result every time. You are right it is very concerning. I have managed to do a successful copy of the database, but even when I export that I have the same problem.

Comment: That's unusual. Are you exporting using the Azure SQL Database Import/Export Service (i.e. the Azure portal) or from SSMS? Either way, we (Microsoft) can most efficiently determine the root cause of this if we work directly with you. Would you be be amenable to sending a mail to sgreen at Microsoft?

Comment: I used the azure website to generate the export. I tried the new portal (portal.microsoft.com) & manage.windowsazure.com. I would assume they both use the same method to export but I need a solution! I did send you an email, did you get it?